# Neo4J Rest interface listener not starting

Tags: neo4j

I have exported a graph of around 1300 nodes and 3500 edges from Gephi 0.8.2 beta into Neo4J 1.9RC1. However, after exporting I cannot connect to the server using REST API anymore because I cannot find any listener either on port 1337 or on port 7474. Hence, neither the shell interface nor the web interface is working.

Everytime I try to connect using the Shell it says "Connection Refused". When run in verbose mode it says "

```
D:\neo4j-enterprise-1.9.RC1\bin>Neo4jShell.bat -v
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
        Connection refused
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
"
```

Could someone please explain what is going on? 
I have checked using netstat that the ports 1337 and 7474 are free and noone else is listening on them.

The same behavior is noticed on Neo4J version 1.8.2 enterprise stable as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to start the shell, not the server. You want to run the `bin\neo4j start` command, then it should be listening on those ports.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.